# Unrecognized keyword. (near "str_to_date" at position 158)

Tags: mysql, date

im trying to create a table and insert values after creating it but im getting a lot of errors [image: thes are my errors]

and this is my create table statement

```
 CREATE TABLE EVENTREQUEST 
 (EVENTNO VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
  DATEHELD DATE NOT NULL, 
  DATEREQ  DATE NOT NULL, 
  CUSTNO VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
  FACNO VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
  DATEAUTH DATE NOT NULL, 
  STATUS VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  ESTCOST DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL,  
  ESTAUDIENCE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  BUDNO VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTREQUEST PRIMARY KEY (EVENTNO)
  CONSTRAINT FKCustNo FOREIGN KEY (CustNo) REFERENCES Customer (CustNo),
  CONSTRAINT FKEmpNo FOREIGN KEY (FACNO) REFERENCES facility (FACNO)  ) ;
```

my insert statements

```
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E100',str_to_date('25,OCT,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('06,JUN,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C100','F100',str_to_date('08,JUN,13','%d,%b,%y'),'Approved',5000,80000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E101',str_to_date('26,OCT,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('28,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C100','F100',null,'Pending',5000,80000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E103',str_to_date('21,SEP,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('28,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C100','F100',str_to_date('01,AUG,13','%d,%b,%y'),'Approved',5000,80000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E102',str_to_date('14,SEP,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('28,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C100','F100',str_to_date('31,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'Approved',5000,80000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E104',str_to_date('03,DEC,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('28,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C101','F101',str_to_date('31,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'Approved',2000,12000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E105',str_to_date('05,DEC,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('28,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C101','F101',str_to_date('01,AUG,13','%d,%b,%y'),'Approved',2000,10000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E106',str_to_date('12,DEC,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('28,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C101','F101',str_to_date('31,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'Approved',2000,10000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E107',str_to_date('23,NOV,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('28,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C105','F100',str_to_date('31,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'Denied',10000,5000,null);
```

how can i resolved this?

Comment: Can you execute the CREATE TABLE and then just the first INSERT?

Comment: I did but not successful getting same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the NULL in this row.

```
 Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values 
('E101',str_to_date('26,OCT,13','%d,%b,%y'),str_to_date('28,JUL,13','%d,%b,%y'),'C100',
'F100',null,'Pending',5000,80000,'B1000');
```

The Field cant be NULL. So change the field type or the Value

Also field BUDNO in the last INSERT

Comment: they are some insert statement without a Null yet they are giving the same error

Comment: i have tested each line. there is also the field BUDNO in the last INSERT. this cant also be NULL

Comment: i went through again and recreated my table then inserted